# react native textAlign justify but also right

Tags: react-native

Setting textAlign to justify, while it does justify RTL scripts like Persian, but it still writes from left, meaning if the line finishes halfway, like this paragraph, it would be obvious that the text it getting written from left, and this is not ideal for RTL languages like Persian.

So how should I justify but write from right?